# C# Slow Paint Event: painting large number of objects

Tags: c#, events, list, gdi, paint

I have a PictureBox it serves as a canvas.
A `List<RectangleObj>` the array size of aprox 8000.

The "RectangleObj" is a simple rectangle class, once you invoke its `Draw(Graphic g)` method it will draw

1. the border using
   `g.DrawRectangle(...)` and,
2. fill the rectangle with an alpha
   transparency using
   `g.FillRectangle(...)`

In the application Form.cs, i use the `pictureBox1_Paint(...)` to loop the array of `RectangleObj` and invoke the `Draw` method of that class.

Like this.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < RectList.Count(); i++) //List<RectangleObj> count = 8000 
          RectList[i].Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

Every time the mouse clicks upon a `RectangleObj` and drags changing its location (mouse move event) the paint event is called. since the array is large in number, the paint event does not have enough time to finish its loop and gets flooded with mouse movements. so, this makes the Paint event slow.

Can somebody advice me how to optimize this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here:

1. don't draw while moving. Calculate an outline for the selected elements and XOR only that outline when the mouse moves. Repaint on MouseUp.
2. don't draw stuff you don't need. You can run an algorithm to detect which rectangles are totally obscured and ignore them.
3. Make sure you have DoubleBuffered=true for your Picturebox

Comment: No need to worry about point #3, the PictureBox control is DoubleBuffered already.

Comment: 4. The OP code runs approximately 10 times faster in RELEASE mode compared to DEBUG.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered drawing to an in memory bitmap, then blitting that to the screen?

Comment: Nope. didn't try that. i will try but i don't think would be successful enough to reduce the time in drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Work out which rectangles need to be redrawn based on the location of the moving rectangle and its prior location and only redraw those. Clip the painting to only those parts that have been invalidated.

Comment: Yes thank you. your answer does help me. but i have another scenario which is.

If the mouse select and move is more than 3000 rectangles. consider this as an example. an image representing a page of a book . each character representing as a rectangle. if the user hits CTRL + A it selects all rectangle and when user moves the mouse it will move all rectangles.

in the above scenario a very large amount of rectangles must be painted. 

This is the last pending concern.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it would be worth while cacheing what has been painted into a bitmap and repainting the entire bitmap.